# Numpy: smart matrix multiplication to sparse result matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

In python with numpy, say I have two matrices:

1. `S`, a sparse `x*x` matrix
2. `M`, a dense `x*y` matrix

Now I want to do `np.dot(M, M.T)` which will return a dense `x*x` matrix `S_`.

However, I only care about the cells that are nonzero in `S`, which means that it would not make a difference for my application if I did

`S_ = S*S_`

Obviously, that would be a waste of operations as I would like to leave out the irrelevant cells given in `S` alltogether. Remember that in matrix multiplication

`S_[i,j] = np.sum(M[i,:]*M[:,j])`

So I want to do this operation only for `i,j` such that `S[i,j]=True`.

Is this supported somehow by numpy implementations that run in C so that I do not need to implement it with python loops?

---

**EDIT 1 [solved]:** *I still have this problem, actually `M` is now also sparse.*

Now, given rows and cols of `S`, I implemented it like this:

```
data = np.array([ M[rows[i],:].dot(M[cols[i],:]).data[0] for i in xrange(len(rows)) ])
S_   = csr( (data, (rows,cols)) )
```

... but it is still slow. *Any new ideas?*

**EDIT 2:** *jdehesa has given a great solution, but I would like to save more memory.*

The solution was to do the following:

```
data = M[rows,:].multiply(M[cols,:]).sum(axis=1)
```

and then build a new sparse matrix from `rows`, `cols` and `data`.

However, when running the above line, scipy builds a (contiguous) numpy array with as many elements as `nnz` of the first submatrix plus `nnz` of the second submatrix, which can lead to `MemoryError` in my case.

In order to save more memory, I would like to multiply iteratively each row with its respective 'partner' column, then sum over and discard the result vector. Using simple python to implement this, basically I am back to the extremely slow version.

Is there a fast way of solving this problem?

Comment: What's the size of these arrays? what's the sparsity of `S`.  A small example might help, just make sure we are on the same page.  Unless `S` is quite sparse the extra selection work might cancel out any calculation time savings.

Comment: The problem is that the output matrix would be too large for memory, if it would be calculated as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with NumPy/SciPy, both for dense and sparse `M` matrices:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

# Coordinates where S is True
S = np.array([[0, 1],
              [3, 6],
              [3, 4],
              [9, 1],
              [4, 7]])

# Dense M matrix
# Random big matrix
M = np.random.random(size=(1000, 2000))
# Take relevant rows and compute values
values = np.sum(M[S[:, 0]] * M[S[:, 1]], axis=1)
# Make result matrix from values
result = np.zeros((len(M), len(M)), dtype=values.dtype)
result[S[:, 0], S[:, 1]] = values

# Sparse M matrix
# Construct sparse M as COO matrix or any other way
M = sp.coo_matrix(([10, 20, 30, 40, 50],  # Data
                   ([0, 1, 3, 4, 6],      # Rows
                    [4, 4, 5, 5, 8])),    # Columns
                  shape=(1000, 2000))
# Convert to CSR for fast row slicing
M_csr = M.tocsr()
# Take relevant rows and compute values
values = M_csr[S[:, 0]].multiply(M_csr[S[:, 1]]).sum(axis=1)
values = np.squeeze(np.asarray(values))
# Construct COO sparse matrix from values
result = sp.coo_matrix((values, (S[:, 0], S[:, 1])), shape=(M.shape[0], M.shape[0]))
```

Comment: This is very promising! However one should note that in this approach, still all rows and cols used will have to be stored as dense representations at the same time, so the memory is still challenged much more than if each target value is computed after the other as in my (slow) approach.

Comment: @RadioControlled In the first case you have a dense matrix `M`, but in the second case you have a sparse matrix, so at no point every row and column will have to be stored.

Comment: Isn't `M_csr[S[:, 0]].toarray()` all the rows from S where at least one cell is not empty? For large sparse matrices this is very likely almost the entire matrix in dense form, as the probability that at least one cell is not empty increases. -- Actually I just tested it and got `MemoryError`

Comment: Although I have to agree that this is more related to my edit than to the original question...

Comment: @RadioControlled Okay I see what you mean. I've changed it to use only sparse operations.

Comment: This is so much faster!